# Xdebug ignores browser plugin and always triggers

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, laradock

Xdebug works perfectly when I turn on the listener in PhpStorm and set break point, but I'm trying to use a browser plugin by which you can toggle xdebug which does not seem to work. Xdebug is triggered even when the browser cookie PHPSTORM is not set.

Setup:

```
Laradock on mac
PhpStorm
PHP 7.1.16
Xdebug 2.6.0
```

I configured xdebug like this:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off
xdebug.remote_host=10.254.254.254
xdebug.remote_port=9005
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1500
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

Comment: 1) provide xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output; 2) Does it behave the same in another browser?; 3) The cookie may still be set. Clear all cookies in the browser

Comment: PhpStorm provides [bookmarklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) you can use to start and stop a debug session from browser. Have you tried them? They work fine for me (I tried them only with Google Chrome).

Comment: @LazyOne 3) this seems to work, which is strange because in the browser I kept checking application -> storage -> cookies and on toggling it appeared and dissapeared. Thanks ;-)

Comment: By Laradock do you mean Laravel + Docker? Because the same exact thing is happening to me with php-fpm + xdebug + docker...

Comment: @santiagoarizti yes